# Unknown variance hypothesis testing for normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid random variables each with a $N(\mu_0,\sigma^2)$ distribution, where $\mu_0$ is known and $\sigma^2$ is unknown. Find the best (most powerful) test of size at most $\alpha$ for testing $H_0:\sigma^2=\sigma_0^2$ against $H_1:\sigma^2=\sigma_1^2$ for known $\sigma_0^2$ and $\sigma_1^2 > \sigma_0^2$.

#### Progress

These are simple hypotheses, so I should be able to use the Neyman-Pearson lemma to find the best test size $\leq \alpha$. However, when I carry out the calculation, I am finding it difficult to simply the likelihood ratio, or to show that it is strictly increasingl (so that I can, for example, just consider the distribution of $\bar X$. The likelihood ratio is

$$\Lambda_{\underline{x}}(H_0;H_1)=\left(\frac{\sigma_0}{\sigma_1}\right)^n \exp\left(\sum(x_i-\mu_0)^2 \left[\frac{1}{2\sigma_0^2}-\frac{1}{2\sigma_1^2}\right]\right)$$

I understand what the Neyman-Pearson lemma states, I just don't understand how we apply it to this particular problem, as it seems that the likelihood ratio I have is too complicated to use: I think there must be a way to distill the essential information from it, perhaps by using monotonicity, but I'm not sure how to implement this in practice.

Comment: Is there a Lemma that you can use if the conditions of the lemma are satisfied? What type of Hypotheses are these (simple or composite)? The type of hypotheses determines if you can use the lemma or the theorem.

Comment: These are simple hypotheses, so I should be able to use the Neyman-Pearson lemma to find the best test size $\leq \alpha$. However, when I carry out the calculation, I am finding it difficult to simply the likelihood ratio, or to show that it is strictly increasingly (so that I can, for example, just consider the distribution of $\bar(X)$

Comment: What do you get as your LRT? Since $\mu$ is known, are they the same regardless if you put $\sigma_{1}^{2}$ or $\sigma_{0}^{2}$ into your equation?

Comment: $\Lambda_{\underline{x}}(H_0;H_1)=(\frac{\sigma_0}{\sigma_1})^n exp(\sum(x_i-\mu_0)^2 [\frac{1}{2\sigma_0^2}-\frac{1}{2\sigma_1^2}])$

Comment: Well, you can foil out $x_{i}-\mu_{0}$ and distribute the sum over that product, and see where that gets you.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that, I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: Sorry about that. So you have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\mu_{0})^{2}$. So when you multiply out $(x_{i}-\mu_{0})^{2} = x_{i}^{2}-2\mu_{0}x_{i}+\mu_{0}^{2}$. So you distribute the sum over that, and you end up with $\sum x_{i}^{2}-2\mu_{0}\sum x_{i} + n\mu_{0}^{2}$.

Comment: How does doing this help me find the critical region for a test of size alpha. Normally what I would do is say that the likelihood is an increasing function of some variable, then look at the distribution of that variable to give me a critical region. However, in this case I can't see why it is true that the likelihood is monotonic.

Comment: Well, before you moved the denominator to the top you could've canceled the $e^{-2\mu\sum x_{i} + n\mu_{0}^{2}}$. That's really all doing that will help you. And then you could move the denominator up, and since $\sigma_{1}^{2}>\sigma_{0}^{2}$, then the larger n gets, the larger $\sigma_{1}$ becomes, so then $(\frac{\sigma_{0}}{\sigma_{1}})^{n} \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} 0$. So your function is strictly decreasing/monotonic.

Comment: Does this mean the critical region will be of the form ${\underline{x}: \bar{X}<k}$ for some $k$, as then the likelihood is a decreasing function if it tends to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$

Comment: By the critical region, do you mean the rejection region? By the conditions that need to be satisfied in order to use NP, $x\in R$, (where R is the rejection region): if $f(\underline{x}\mid\theta_{1}) > f(\underline{x}\mid\theta_{0})$ and $x\in R^{c}$ ($R^{c}$ = acceptance region): if $f(\underline{x}\mid\theta_{1}) < f(\underline{x}\mid\theta_{0})$ and if $\alpha = P(\underline{x} \in R)$

Comment: Yes I do mean the rejection region. I understand what the NP lemma states, I just don't understand how we apply it to this particular problem, as it seems that the likelihood ratio I have is too complicated to use: I think there must be a way to distil the essential information from it, perhaps by using monotonicity, but I'm not sure how to implement this in practice.

Comment: Okie dokie. So I found a great pdf, found [here][1] that might help. The help starts around page 4 of the pdf, which is pertinent to your question.

[1]:http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~churvich/Regress/Handouts/Chapt7.pdf

Comment: Thank you, this helps, the explanation of why we can just look at $\bar{x}$ is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You are most certainly welcome. :) I'm glad that I could help, and it helped me to understand NP a little bit better, too!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3607509/321264